# How to change default ganache-cli ip address in brownie ide?

Tags: brownie

When I run `brownie console` the ganache-cli starts by default at `127.0.0.1` address. How to change this address to `0.0.0.0`?

I've tried to modified config located at `~/.brownie/network-config.yaml`. I've changed `host` and `port` in the following section

```yaml
development:
  - name: Ganache-CLI
    id: development
    cmd: ganache-cli
    host: http://0.0.0.0
    cmd_settings:
      port: 8549
      gas_limit: 12000000
      accounts: 10
      evm_version: istanbul
      mnemonic: brownie
```

but after restart only port was updated correcly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Edit the network
2. Add a new network with the URL you're looking for

### Edit the network

```sh
brownie networks modity development host=http://0.0.0.0
```

### Add a new network

```sh
brownie networks add development ganache-zero cmd=ganache-cli host=http://0.0.0.0 accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```

Or

```sh
brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-zero host=http://0.0.0.0:8545 chainid=1337
```